# CoreLocation stopped working for a couple of app users

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, core-location

I have an app that relies on CoreLocation. In the last week I've had two users send me an email letting me know that location doesn't work anymore in the app. It's a fairly straightforward app that has the ability to display weather based on your current location.

The users swear that location services is enabled, even for the app specifically. In both cases, everything worked perfectly when they first purchased the app but stopped working all of a sudden (their words).

I've had them do several things for me like use other apps that use location services to see if they work or try from alternate locations. They've even uninstalled my app and re-installed to no avail.

Am I crazy or is the users? It just sounds farfetched to me, but I'm far from an expert at this. In both cases they're using an iPod Touch and/or iPad wifi only model. Both are running 5.0.x.

A re-install of the app should certainly reset things to default, right? Do remnants of an app linger around only to be used on a re-install?

Answer (score 2):

In looking through my code I realized that I changed from StartUpdatingLocation to StartMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges which only works on the iPhone 3GS and up. Since it doesn't work on the iPad/iPod Touch this was creating my issue. I changed my code to start the app using StartUpdatingLocation and once a location is received switch over to StartMonitoringSignficantLocationChanges. This resolved the issue for all iOS devices.